# How to Delete a blank excelsheet from a workbook in C#.net

Tags: c#, excel-2010, worksheet

I have an excel workbook which has multiple worksheets being added to it inside a loop from another workbook. I need to identify if the sheet, that is being added to new workbook from an old workbook, is empty/blank then don't add it to the new workbook. I tried using oledbadapter and read the workbook but that opens the workbook during the operation which I'm trying to read. 
Does anybody have any idea if I can achieve that with the help of an excel inbuilt blank check method.?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to check if a sheet inside a workbook is empty or not without opening the file. You wouldn't be able to go by file size, because even a blank workbook will have header information and make the file size greater than zero. Your best bet is to use Excel [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and check the [UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.usedrange%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Awesome... UsedRange worked flawlessly. This is what I did..>

foreach (Worksheet wSheet in _wbook.Worksheets) {
    Range sheetsUsedRange = wSheet.UsedRange;
    if (sheetsUsedRange.Columns.Count <= 1) {
                                wSheet.Delete();
                                break;
                            }                           
                        }

Thanks Much
Amrit

Comment: You're welcome, Amrit. Glad you could make it work for your needs!